Bounded operators with closed complemented ranges
Let $B$ be a Banach space and $A:B\rightarrow B$ a bounded operator such that $A\left( B\right) $ is closed and there is some closed subspace $E\subset B$ such that $B=A\left( B\right) \oplus E$. Is there some neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $B=\left( A-\lambda \right) \left( B\right) +E$ for all $\lambda \in V$ ?
I know that $\ker \left( A\right) $ may not have a closed complementary subspace, but I still believe that this statement is true. So, any help please ?

recall that the set of surjective (linear, bounded) operators  on B  is open  in L(B).  So you can take every $A’$  in some nbd of $A$  (more generally than $A’:=A-\lambda$)

In your conditions you do not need to assume that $A(B)$ is closed. This is a consequence of $B=A(B)\oplus E$ with $E$ closed.

In  fact it would be sufficient to assume $B=A(B)+E$, that is  the operator $B\times E\ni (x,y)\mapsto Ax+y\in  B$ is surjective.

Thank you so much @PietroMajer

Is the set of continuous surjective operators between two Fréchet spaces open too ? @PietroMajer

So What if $B$ is a Fréchet space ?@PietroMajer

Nice question .  I think the answer in general is no, but there could be special spaces for which is still true —You may want to post it as a new question.

I'll do @PietroMajer

Denoting $Q_E:B\to B/E$ the quotient map, $Q_EA$ is surjective. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $Q_E(A-\lambda)$ is surjective, hence $B=(A-\lambda)(B)+E$, for $|\lambda|<r$.
